# Save PCM raw bytes into a DataView object

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm acquiring PCM raw bytes with `new AudioContext({ sampleRate: 16000 })` (note, I'm using Chrome, which supports the `sampleRate` option), and I'd like to convert the resulting array into a `DataView` object.

My current code is the following, in the `stop` method I read the left channel and store it as an array of `Float32Array`s.

```js
function mergeBuffers(channelBuffer, recordingLength) {
  let result = new Float32Array(recordingLength);
  let offset = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < channelBuffer.length; i++) {
    result.set(channelBuffer[i], offset);
    offset += channelBuffer[i].length;
  }

  return Array.prototype.slice.call(result);
}

class AudioRecorder {
  constructor(audioStream, config) {
    this.audioStream = audioStream;

    // creates the an instance of audioContext
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext({ sampleRate: 16000 });

    // retrieve the current sample rate of microphone the browser is using
    this.sampleRate = this.audioContext.sampleRate;

    // creates a gain node
    this.volume = this.audioContext.createGain();

    // creates an audio node from the microphone incoming stream
    this.audioInput = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);

    this.leftChannel = [];
    this.recordingLength = 0;

    /*
     * From the spec: This value controls how frequently the audioprocess event is
     * dispatched and how many sample-frames need to be processed each call.
     * Lower values for buffer size will result in a lower (better) latency.
     * Higher values will be necessary to avoid audio breakup and glitches
     */
    const bufferSize = config?.bufferSize ?? 2048;
    this.recorder = (
      this.audioContext.createScriptProcessor ||
      this.audioContext.createJavaScriptNode
    ).call(this.audioContext, bufferSize, 1, 1);

    // connect the stream to the gain node
    this.audioInput.connect(this.volume);

    this.recorder.onaudioprocess = (event) => {
      const samples = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

      // we clone the samples
      this.leftChannel.push(new Float32Array(samples));

      this.recordingLength += bufferSize;
    };
    
    this.ondataavailable = config?.ondataavailable;
  }

  start() {
    // we connect the recorder
    this.volume.connect(this.recorder);

    // start recording
    this.recorder.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
    
    
  }

  stop() {
    this.recorder.disconnect();
    const PCM32fSamples = mergeBuffers(this.leftChannel, this.recordingLength);
    const PCM16iSamples = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < PCM32fSamples.length; i++) {
      let val = Math.floor(32767 * PCM32fSamples[i]);
      val = Math.min(32767, val);
      val = Math.max(-32768, val);

      PCM16iSamples.push(val);
    }
    
    return PCM16iSamples;
  }
}

(async () => {
  if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    alert("getUserMedia not supported in this browser.");
  }

  let audioStream;
  try {
    audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    });
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Error capturing audio.");
  }

  const recorder = new AudioRecorder(audioStream);
  
  document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', () => recorder.start());
  document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(recorder.stop()));
})();
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

In order to send this recording to my backend I need to convert the array into a `DataView`, so I tried to do the following:

```js
stop() {
    this.recorder.disconnect();
    const PCM32fSamples = mergeBuffers(this.leftChannel, this.recordingLength);
    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(PCM32fSamples.length + 1);
    const PCM16iSamples = new DataView(buffer);

    for (let i = 0; i < PCM32fSamples.length; i++) {
      let val = Math.floor(32767 * PCM32fSamples[i]);
      val = Math.min(32767, val);
      val = Math.max(-32768, val);

      PCM16iSamples.setInt16(i, val);
    }
    
    return PCM16iSamples;
  }
```

But the problem is that the resulting audio is inaudible.

From my understanding, the `AudioContext` is returning a list of `Float32Array` no matter what `sampleRate` I set it to use, so I don't understand what am I supposed to do to convert the values so that they fit into a `Int16` buffer...

Comment: How are you trying to play it?

Comment: Nothing specific, it's going to a server where it gets processed for speech-to-text. I'm opening the samples with Audacity though (and with the browser HTML player also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I will assume you know how to handle s16le raw audio.

Also notice that you are creating your ArrayBuffer with length equals the number of samples in the `PCM32fSamples`, should be the size in bytes, also the call to `setInt16` should pass the offset in bytes.

An alternative to set an array buffer is to construct an [Int16Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array/Int16Array). The motivation for using a DataView is to be able to write mixed type data. This will make your code more readable.

```
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(this.recordingLength * 2);
  const PCM16iSamples = new Int16Array(buffer);
  let offset = 0;
  for(const chunk of this.leftChannel){
    for(const sample of chunk){
      let val = Math.floor(32767 * sample);
      val = Math.min(32767, val);
      val = Math.max(-32768, val);
      PCM16iSamples[offset++] = val;
    }
  }
```

In the end the data will be on the `PCM16iSamples` and in the `buffer`, you can construct the dataview from the buffer as you did in your example

PS I didn't test, the snipped does not work here.

To populate using `DataView`

```
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(this.recordingLength * 2);
  const data = new DataView(buffer);
  let offset = 0;
  for(const chunk of this.leftChannel){
    for(const sample of chunk){
      let val = Math.floor(32767 * sample);
      val = Math.min(32767, val);
      val = Math.max(-32768, val);
      data.setInt16(offset, val) = val;
      offset += 2;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please show me how to populate the DataView also?

Comment: You could use the first approach and then construct `new DataView(buffer)` or if you prefer using the dataview I added a second version

Comment: Umh there's something wrong... Please listen to this recording, I said "1 2 3 4 5" https://anonymousfiles.io/Z96daJpk/

Comment: Oh nevermind! I forgot to reset the leftChannel after each read  Thanks again!